# What should I research if I want to enable "profile" features for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I just finished my iPhone programming class and created my first app. My app has a feature that does mutiple sound recordings (to the documents directory) from the microphone and displays a title (which the user inputs as well.)

As a next step for my application I wanted to be able to allow the user to take these saved recordings and titles and be able to share them with other users who have my app as well as import other user's recordings.  I wanted to do this within my application.

My question is, what framework or topics should I be reading about in order to do something like this? The idea would be so that users could trade and share "profiles", as I call them.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading as your coined "profile" term can be confused with the provisioning profiles in iOS.  In any event, to achieve what you are looking to do, you will need to have some sort of server host these recordings.  I think all of these apps are doing something similar to what you are talking about.  http://www.appolicious.com/curated-apps/4515-audio-recording-and-sharing-oct-2011

Comment: As weird as it sounds, gamekit is the optimal framework for sending small files over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna share things with each other, integrating with Facebook might be the easiest way. It provides a quick way of creating users, and selecting people who you wanna send your files to. The Facebook API allows you to pull your profile picture and your friends list, which can be used for both of your needs. Though this project of yours sounds like it would need some back-end work too. Since it's just a small project and you probably wanna get it done quickly, I would highly recommend Parse. We use them for our startup and the services they provide are phenomenal and super simple. And it's completely free up to a pretty solid level of usage.

In Short, here are my suggestions: Look at the Facebook API for user capabilities (picture, name, etc.)
Look at Parse for your back-end. And look at push notifications (not a framework) for implementing sending. You can have them query for results when they receive a push.

Comment: Cool thanx I will chech these out.